# The expected value of a compound lottery.

Tags: probability, expected-value

At the casino, a dealer suggested that you participate in a game.
The game will be played in the following way.

Step 1: Before participating in the game, you choose a real number $q$ between 0 and 1 and announce the number to dealer.

Step 2:  Then, the dealer will extract following four variables from the lottery machine (random number generator).

Variable $p$ is real and has the uniform
distribution between $[0,1]$.

Variable $r$ is real and has the uniform distribution between $[0,1]$.

Variable $x$ is real and has the uniform distribution between $[\underline{x},\bar{x}]$.

Variable $y$ is real and has the uniform distribution between $[\underline{y},\bar{y}]$.

Step 3: . If $x\geq qy$, you get the $x$ reward. If $x<qy$ and $r<p$, you get the $y$ reward. If $x<qy$ and $r\geq p$, you get no reward (=zero).

If you declared a number of $q$ before joining the game, what is the expected value of the reward for participating this game where the numbers $\underline{x},\bar{x},\underline{y},\bar{y}$ are given)?

Comment: $E($"reward"$)= E(x 1_{\{x\geq qy\}}) + E(y 1_{\{x< qy\}}) P(r< p)$. Both expectations and the probability just become double integrals. Assuming the random number generator generates independent numbers.

Comment: Yes. I assumed that the random number generator generates independent numbers. Thank you.